# Software for developing chat programs

Tags: web-applications

I  am trying to determine the best software to use to build a web based chat application.  Any thoughts on which applications to use?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You might want to read the [introductionary tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) - your question is far off topic.

Comment: Thanks to Mohammad Faizan for his response.  His answer was very helpful.  Not sure why people think the topic was off topic.  The two responses were actually quite helpful.  The comment about "this question being worthless" certainly shows people's stupidity.  As a newcomer, I would expect a little more support as opposed to being attached for asking a question that other's feel is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Nodejs\ExpressJS,  [socketIO](http://socket.io/) it really best. NodeJS is best or you can use asp.net with [signalR](http://signalr.net/) or you can also try [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#tutorial/basic/0).